# String (x,y) to Object {x, y}

Tags: javascript, regex

What would be the most efficient way to convert a PostgreSQL point in the format of `"(5.035,1)"` to `{x: 5.035, y: 1}`?

The function I wrote in PHP looks like

```
function pointToArray($point) {
    if ( strlen($point) == 0 ) return null;

    $xy = explode(",", substr($point, 1, strlen($point)-2));

    return array(
        "x" => $xy[0], 
        "y" => $xy[1]
    );
}
```

Comment: How is your PHP code related to your JavaScript code? How/where are you calling that function?

Comment: @FelixKling - Initially I was converting the array of strings to an array of arrays  and then converting it to a JSON object - but it took up too much memory.

Comment: How many points are we talking about? I cannot believe that this consumes a lot of memory.

Comment: My preference with these has always been regex, something like: `function conv(s) { var rx = /\(([^,]+),\s*([^)]+)\)/g; var m = rx.exec(s); return { x: m[1], y: m[2]};}`. It helps with more unpredictable input (eg: if there are extra spaces floating around)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same approach in Javascript as you did in your PHP:

```
function pointToObject(point) {
  if(!point.length) return null;
  var split = point.slice(1, -1).split(",");
  return {
    x: +split[0],
    y: +split[1]
  };
}
```

A naive benchmark I just did was able to execute this function 2 million times in 1.53 seconds.

And, just for good measure, here's a regex solution shamelessly stolen from NullUserException that is [marginally faster](http://jsperf.com/point-conversion/8) on most browsers

```
function conv(s) { 
   var rx = /\(([^,]+),\s*([^)]+)\)/g; 
   var m = rx.exec(s); 
   return (!m ? null : { x: +m[1], y: +m[2]}); 
}
```

Comment: @NullUserException I'm pretty sure `String.prototype.slice` works in IE8 and IE7. I have no idea if it works in IE6 or not.

Comment: Thanks for all of your input.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that *point* in the question means a geographic point one could extract the numbers using `ST_X` and `ST_Y`. The values can then be recombined using the string concatenation of Postgres (or using its JSON functions if using a current version).

Doing the transformation in SQL is probably faster and more reliable than using PHP of JavaScript for the purpose.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by `ST_X` and `ST_Y`? I'm not quite sure how this applies to my question.

Comment: I assumed you store your point in Postgres in a way that Postgres knows it is a point. The functions will extract the numbers from the point without requiring to go through a conversion to string first. See documentation of PostGIS (geography related functions for Postgres) http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_X.html for further explanations.
If you do not use PostGIS see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-geometry.html at the very bottom where the index based access with the same meaning is presented.

Comment: I'll look into this. Something tells me that I may still run into the memory problem of having too large of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

This one avoids the overhead of creating a string array for the split:

```
function pointToObject(point) {
   var i = point.indexOf(",");
   if(i==-1) return null;
   return {
     x: point.substr(1, i-1),
     y: point.substr(i+1, point.length-i-2)
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked this when I posted it - there actually isn't a space after the comma. I've edited my post to reflect this change.

Comment: You should probably ensure that `x` and `y` get converted into numbers

Comment: Performance-wise, I think I'm in the lead... http://jsperf.com/point-conversion/5

I've adjusted the code for no space.

Comment: @Alnitak Ensuring that x and y get converted to numbers made its performance drop quite a bit for me: http://jsperf.com/point-conversion/6

Comment: Revision 5 and 6 are flawed because points are being cached. You getter more informative results if you generate a [new point each time](http://jsperf.com/point-conversion/8).

Comment: I revised to ensure the regex version also returns numbers, and this one eeks out a win again:

http://jsperf.com/point-conversion/9

Answer (score 0):

This is short, but nasty, taking advantage of the fact that `(x, y)` kinda looks like a parameter list:

```
function c(x, y) {
    return {x:x, y:y};
};

p = "(5.035, 1)";
a = eval("c" + p);
```

Comment: If I have complete control of the input, is this a pracitcal solution?

Comment: @Wex It will work, but it will be comparatively slow because it has to invoke an entire Javascript interpreter.

Comment: @PeterOlson true, it probably isn't very efficient

Comment: @Alnitak - thanks for the response, but I did specifically state "most efficient" :)

Comment: @Wex I tested it - on Chrome 22 my `eval` based version is faster than Peter's - http://jsperf.com/point-conversion

Comment: @Alnitak I beat them both with regex: http://jsperf.com/point-conversion/2 Where do I collect my cookie?

Comment: @NullUserException yes, I just added your regex too - surprised that it's faster than the split-based method.

Comment: Here's one that makes a new point each time. eval is much slower, regex is still fastest. http://jsperf.com/point-conversion/3

Comment: ah, the old adage, lies, damned lies, and jsperf benchmarks ;-)

Comment: @PeterOlson I added the `+` to convert stuff to numbers, added a check to make sure the regex matches and it's [*still* faster](http://jsperf.com/point-conversion/4). Im' a bit surprised, actually.

Comment: @NullUserException: not for me; the `explicit` is ~6x faster than `eval`, and `regex` is ~7x faster than `eval`.